# How to transform elements array into JSONPath Syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following structure:

```
let employee = {
    skill: "English",
    person: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Mike"
  }
}
```

I have the string "person_lastName" that represents the path from the structure.
In case the string is split by "_", then it is transformed into an array
`['person','lastName']`

How to transform this array into JSONPath syntax?
['person'][lastName']

Any other idea to compose the jsonPath based on the mentioned string is welcome!
I mention that I have a lot of structure and strings that represent the path from a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const isObject = x => x !== null && typeof x === 'object'

function getPath(path, obj) {
  // not an object, so we can't get a value from it
  if(!isObject(obj)) {
    return undefined
  }
  
  const key = path[0]
  
  // this is the last value in path
  if(path.length === 1) {
    return obj[key]
  }
  
  // the path without the first value
  const restPath = path.slice(1)
  
  return getPath(restPath, obj[key])
}

const employee = {
    skill: "English",
    person: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Mike"
  }
}

const pathStr = 'person_lastName'
const pathArr = pathStr.split('_')

console.log(getPath(pathArr, employee))
```